# Getting "Param is missing or the value is empty: user" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I can't figure out how to route this correctly. I keep getting this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: user
app/controllers/user_controller.rb:72:in 'user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in 'create'
```

Here is line 27:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  ...
end
```

Here is line 72:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

This is the _form.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :user_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, id: :user_email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong in simpler terms?
Thank you.

Comment: How about you update your question with your console output (including the error) so that we can see that it doesn't contain the `:user` key? And then, perhaps, your view so that we can see that `:name` and `:email` aren't nested inside `:user`? Or, maybe the errors and views won't show those things...

Comment: Your params isn't wrapped in `user` key. Check your form in view. It should have something like this `<%= form_for @user .............%>`. In this case all data in form will be wrapped in `user` key.

Comment: @Dishmaster add form from your view.

Comment: Strange that in your view you have just `user` because this variable might be not defined in `new` action. Try to use `@user`

Comment: @nautgrad I tried that and it would not work, got the same error.

Comment: Make the @user change everywhere you’re currently using user.

Comment: @hashrocket everywhere on the file?

Comment: Everywhere in your _form.html.erb

Comment: @hashrocket tried that but still getting the same error. Could you think of what else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Try taking the id off of the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the view ***views/users/new.html.erb*** (the view that includes the form). Without that, we cannot know if the partial (_form.html.erb) local variable `user` has been set.

You can change `user` by `@user` in the form as many recommend, but this is not a good approach. You can use instance variables in views, but if you call a partial <%= render .... %>, you should instantiate the variables you need and don't rely on global @variables. This way you can reuse your partial more easily.

So you should do: `<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { user: @user }`, assuming you have created a new @user (`@user = User.new`) in **UsersController#new**

Answer (score 0):

you should write the form like this 

`= form_for @user do |f|`
 
while `@user` is a new object of User model. it's better to create it in your `new` action